# Pattern, ignore '&' and subsequent characters if they contain any specific characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Example, I have 3 String:

```
String A = "&aHi"; // true, 2 characters in total
String B = "Hi"; // true, 2 characters in total
String C = "Hi!"; // false, 3 characters in total
```

When the string contains "&" followed by some character like "[0-9A-FK-ORX]" I want it to be excluded in the check if the string is less than 3 characters or greater than 15 characters.

This is what I currently have:
Pattern:

```
"^(?i)(?:(?!&[0-9A-FK-ORX]).|^.{0,2}|^.{16,})$"
```

but I can't get it to work, I'm trying to get it to ignore lower and upper case, I'm checking that it's less than 3 or greater than 15, but I can't get what I need.

Comment: Are you trying to extract known tokens from the string (e.g. replacing `&someData` with the data referenced by `someData`)? If so, there are much better ways than a regex in my opinion. Otherwise, I'm not following what truly determines what strings belong, and which don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your pattern and remove all matches from the string. Then check if the string has less than 3 or more than 15 characters.

```
String[] strings = {"&aHi", "Hi", "Hi!"};

for (String s : strings) {
    int len = s.replaceAll("(?i)&[0-9A-FK-ORX]","").length();
    if (len < 3 || len > 15) {
        System.out.println("VALID --> " + s + ". (" + len + " characters)");
    } else {
        System.out.println("INVALID --> " + s + " ("+ len + " characters)");
    }
}
```

Output

```
VALID --> &aHi. (2 characters)
VALID --> Hi. (2 characters)
INVALID --> Hi! (3 characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `|` symbol in regex is not a-alike to an if-conditional statement.

It's simply saying the regex should match A, B, or C, etc.

The following should be correct, let me know if I have made an error.

```
(?i)(?:(?:&[0-9A-FK-ORX])?.{16,}|(?:&[0-9A-FK-ORX])?..)
```

Here it is, with your variables.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String A = "&aHi"; // true, 2 characters in total
    String B = "Hi"; // true, 2 characters in total
    String C = "Hi!"; // false, 3 characters in total
    System.out.println(valid(A));
    System.out.println(valid(B));
    System.out.println(valid(C));
}

static boolean valid(String string) {
    return string.matches("(?i)(?:(?:&[0-9A-FK-ORX])?.{16,}|(?:&[0-9A-FK-ORX])?..)");
}
```

Output

```
true
true
false
```